# How to concatenate multiple record data into one record?

Tags: sql, vba, report, ms-access-2010

A picture is worth a thousand words, so I'll show you what I'm trying to accomplish first:

[image]

This is a report representing a schedule over the month of September.

The data is obtained from three tables: Employees, Employees_Shifts, and Shifts.

The Report's RecordSource property uses the following query to get the names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name
FROM 
    Shifts 
INNER JOIN 
    (Employees 
INNER JOIN 
    Employees_Shifts ON Employees.Employee_ID = Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID) 
    ON Shifts.Shift_ID = Employees_Shifts.Shift_ID
WHERE 
    (((Shifts.Schedule_ID) = 1))
ORDER BY 
    Employees.Last_Name;
```

So now I'm at the really tricky part where I need to populate all the textboxes with the appropriate data.  Each textbox is supposed to hold one letter: A,B,C,D, etc.

Each of these is a letter "designation" assigned to any given Shift.  You can have multiple shifts happening at the same time but in different locations.  FYI, notice the "Part 1" in the header.  I intend to make a second report that goes more into detail on each shift which you can lookup the letter designation for any given day.  But that's not pertinent to this particular problem.

I need to somehow query the database for the "designation" field in the Shifts table so that I can assign all the letters: A,B,C,D, etc. into the appropriate boxes.

For instance the output of such a query maybe looks like this:

```
Allen             Nelli     3A,7B,10A,13A,14B,17B,19C,21A
Barlow_Steeves    Donna     1A,3B,7A,13B,18A,23A,25A
Beno              Wayne     1B,7B,8A,10A,14B,15C
```

The number/letter combination would represent day and designation together so that I can somehow assign the right letter into the appropriate textbox.
I don't even know if this is at all possible using SQL.  I tried tinkering with this query:

```
SELECT distinct 
    Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name, 
    Day(Shifts.Start_Date_Time) & Shifts.Designation AS Expr1
FROM 
    Shifts 
INNER JOIN 
    (Employees 
INNER JOIN 
    Employees_Shifts ON Employees.Employee_ID = Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID) 
    ON Shifts.Shift_ID = Employees_Shifts.Shift_ID
WHERE 
    (((Shifts.Schedule_ID) = 1));
```

However, this gives me the following output:

```
8  Allen     Nelli     10A
8  Allen     Nelli     13A
8  Allen     Nelli     14B
etc.
```

I don't want every employee showing up in the report multiple times like that.  That's why I used the DISTINCT operator in the original query.

Surely there is a way to query this database so that I can assign the appropriate letter in each textbox using its ControlSource property? Or even just doing a separate query and assign the letter to the Value property of each textbox using vba code?

Any assistance/direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be beneficial for you to create a sub query that aggregates the shift designations based on the employeeid. Do an inner join on this sub query with the employee table. Once you have the designations aggregated, you can simply use the aggregated designations instead of "Shifts.Designation". You may also need to do a group by.

Comment: I don't have any experience with sub queries but have attempted the following sub query: SELECT Day(Shifts.Start_Date_Time) & Shifts.Designation & "," AS Expr1
FROM Shifts INNER JOIN (Employees INNER JOIN Employees_Shifts ON Employees.Employee_ID = Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID) ON Shifts.Shift_ID = Employees_Shifts.Shift_ID;  Again, however, I can't seem to make one record show with multiple concatenated designations.  I think I need some help on the sub query.  Expected possible output: 1B,7B,8A,10A,14B,15C

Comment: I found an answer to my problem on this website: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html